# How to deal with the dependency between two async thunks

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have two async thunks created by `createAsyncThunk()` function of `redux-toolkit`.

E.g.

```
const getOrder = createAsyncThunk('a/getOrder', async (_, thunkAPI) => {
  // `userId` from API.getUser()
  // I tried to get the `userId` from redux store, but got `undefined`.
  const user = thunkAPI.getState().user;
  const userId = user.userId;

  const response = await APIs.getOrder(userId);
  return response.result;
});

const getUser = createAsyncThunk('a/getUser', async () => {
  const response = await APIs.getUser();
  return response.result;
});
```

In component, I dispatched these two async thunks concurrently.

```
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(getUser());
  dispatch(getOrder());
}, []);
```

`getOrder` thunk depend on the result of `getUser()` thunk. What's the correct way to get the `userId` parameter? Can I get the `userId` from the redux store `user` slice state?

Answer (score 3):

> Can I get the userId from the redux store user slice state?

You can access the state in the thunk, but you can't get the `userId` if it doesn't exist yet.

It doesn't make sense to `dispatch` the two thunks concurrently when the call to `APIs.getUser()` must be completed before the call to `APIs.getOrder(userId)` can begin.

---

I recommend that `getOrder` takes the `userId` as an argument.  You can get the `userId` from `await`-ing the resolution of the first `dispatch`.

```
import { isFulfilled } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
```

```
useEffect(() => {
  const load = async () => {
    // is either a fulfilled or rejected action
    const action = await dispatch(getUser());
    if (isFulfilled(action)) {
      dispatch(getOrder(action.payload.userId));
    }
  };
  load();
}, [dispatch]);
```

---

Alternatively, you can `dispatch` the second action in a separate `useEffect` that depends on a `userId` variable selected from the state.

```
// is initially undefined, but then becomes an id
const userId = useSelector(state => state.user?.userId);

const dispatch = useDispatch();

// call getUser on mount
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(getUser());
}, [dispatch]);

// call getOrder after you already have a userId
useEffect(() => {
  if (userId) {
    dispatch(getOrder(userId));
  }
}, [dispatch, userId]);
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would create a third thunk which can handle the async results, some kind of wrapper/helper thunk. The order and user getter thunks should be as minimal as possible. In that third thunk you can implement any complex logic based on the responses and any other stuff you would like to use and wait until you get back the user then call the order api endpoint with the desired params.